# mentions vs mentioned verb tense when summarizing news article

Tags: verbs

Which of one of the following sentences is correct?

> Last week I read a news article that mentions how human activities are causing global warming.
>
> Last week I read a news article that mentioned how human activities are causing global warming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question! Either is correct, but *mentioned* is more idiomatic.

If you were talking about a past conversation you had with a person, rather than reading an article, then it would be clear that the *mentioning* took place in the past:

> Last week I talked to Jim, and he **mentioned** how human activities are causing global warming.

It's not so clear-cut when you're talking about reading an article; either is correct, but seeing as we use the past tense in other cases (like the above), we're more likely to use it here as well. Still, *mentions* is okay, because even though you read the article in the past, the article still exists, and so would still be *mentioning* that fact to anyone who picked it up. A similar example:

> Yesterday I saw a documentary that **talks** about life in New York.

You can use *talks* here, just as you can use *mentions* in your original sentence. The documentary still exists, and is still *talking* about New York to anyone who watches it. But you're more likely to hear a native speaker using *talked* because they're thinking of the time in the past when *they* watched it. So I'd stick with *mentioned* in your case:

> Last week I read a news article that **mentioned** how human activities are causing global warming.

(Though you might also note that *mentioned that* reads a bit better than *mentioned how*.)

Comment: I find that I use *mentions* in contexts where I'm contemplating a future use. For example if I'm telling my friend about the article *so that he might go read it* i.e. it's still relevant in the present, and I'll use the past tense *mentioned* when I am just relaying information about having read it but no future use is contemplated.  Thus:  *I read an article that mentions how a flux capacitor works- you should go read it.*  But: *I once read an article that mentioned how a flux capacitor works, but it was a load of crap.*

Comment: Some native speakers favor the present tense in this context.  (*Some native speakers* is me!)  This blog post does a good job of explaining why: http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/01/literary-present.html